# pyautogui issue with Pystray

Tags: python, pyautogui, pystray

Having issue with pyautogui and pystray.  Using python Version 3.6.4.
Simply importing both modules into the same script and calling any pyautogui function produces an error.
Is there a fix to this or a work around??  I simply want to use the functionality of pyautogui and build a program which resides in the system tray.

```
import pyautogui
import pystray

pyautogui.moveTo(10,10)
```

*expected LP_POINT instance instead of pointer to POINT*

Answer (score 2):

I'm the creator of PyAutoGUI. Thanks for bringing up this issue, I've put in a fix in version 0.9.53 that fixes this. This probably also fixes compatibility issues with other modules, so I'm glad you brought this up.

The details are: PyAutoGUI recreated its own POINT struct which was identical to the one in ctypes.wintypes, but for some reason this was causing problems when another module used ctypes.wintypes.POINT, so I changed PyAutoGUI to use the wintypes one instead.

Comment: Glad I could bring improvements to my favourite language.